# Are there any special deployment requirements for a REST Service to Azure?

Tags: wcf, azure, wcf-rest

I have written a REST service with windows azure using the WCF Rest Service Templates.

Locally everything runs fine. However when I deploy to Azure then all my requests return 500 Server Error.

Are there any special deployment requirements for a REST Service to Azure ?
I don't see anything in my project that points to local.

I left everything in the web.config set to defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remote desktop into the Azure instance and check the Application Log. See [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg443832.aspx) on how to connect to the remote server instance. Most likely you are missing an assembly reference.